# How to detect invalid kwargs?

Tags: python, inheritance, keyword-argument

I'm trying to develop a mechanism to detect invalid kwargs that is robust to inheritance.  I want to create a class with an init method that checks for unexpected kwargs, and I want to create another class that inherits from this first class with the same kwarg checking.  This could go deeper than two layers, but I think getting it solved for two layers allows for further extrapolation.  Here's my attempt:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # possible kwargs and default values
        self._kwargs_def = {
            'a':1, 
            'b':2,
            'c':3,
            }
        self.a = kwargs.pop('a', self._kwargs_def['a'])
        self.b = kwargs.pop('b', self._kwargs_def['b'])
        self.c = kwargs.pop('c', self._kwargs_def['c'])

        assert len(kwargs) == 0, f"Invalid kwargs: {kwargs.keys()}"
        
class MyChildClass(MyClass):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super.__init__() # run once to generate _kwargs_def
        # repeat to override defaults with any appropriate kwargs
        super.__init__(**{key:val for key, val in kwargs.items() if key in super._kwargs_def})
    
        self._kwargs_def.update({'d':4, 'e':5})
        
        self.d = kwargs.pop('d', self._kwargs_def['d'])
        self.e = kwargs.pop('e', self._kwargs_def['e'])
        
        assert len(kwargs) == 0, f"Invalid kwargs: {kwargs.keys()}"
        
my_instance = MyClass(a=7) # works
# I need a way around this: TypeError: descriptor '__init__' of 'super' object needs an argument
my_child_instance = MyChildClass(e=37) # doesn't work but should???
my_instance = MyClass(z=7) # fails and should fail
my_child_instance = MyChildClass(z=37) # fails but for wrong reason
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: Calling `super().__init__()` twice doesn't seem safe in general. `__init__()` methods often have side effects and they're not intended to be called multiple times.

Comment: Your second call to `super().__init__()` checks the kwards you're passing, but doesn't remove them from your `kwargs` dictionary. So your `len(kwargs)` check fails because the parent's keywords are still in the dictionary.

Comment: Typo: `super.__init__()` should be `super().__init__()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made this harder than it needs to be.  Note that I have no code at all in the derived class.

```
class MyClass(object):
    kwargs_def = {
        'a':1, 
        'b':2,
        'c':3,
    }
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # possible kwargs and default values
        assert all(k in self.kwargs_def for k in kwargs), f"Invalid kwargs: {kwargs.keys()}"
        self.__dict__.update( self.kwargs_def )
        self.__dict__.update( kwargs )
        
class MyChildClass(MyClass):
    kwargs_def = MyClass.kwargs_def.copy()
    kwargs_def.update({
        'd':4,
        'e':5
    })
        
my_instance = MyClass(a=7) # works
my_child_instance = MyChildClass(e=37) # doesn't work but should???
my_instance = MyClass(z=7) # fails and should fail
my_child_instance = MyChildClass(z=37) # fails but for wrong reason
```

Comment: You need a copy in `kwargs_def = MyClass.kwargs_def`, or you'll mutate the base class's `kwargs_def` directly.

Comment: Good catch.  Totally missed it.  I wish we had dictionary addition, like a set union.

Comment: Also, `kwargs_def` is supposed to supply defaults, but you're not using them.

Comment: (As of Python 3.9, [dicts do have a union operator](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#dictionary-merge-update-operators).)

Comment: The edit queue is full, but I'd propose passing `a=42` to the first instantiation of MyChildClass to show that it can take arguments used in MyClass.  I'd also put the two intentional failures inside try ... except statements.  Otherwise, this is a clean solution.

Comment: Also, note that 37 is the age of the peasant whom King Arthur addressed as "old woman" in Holy Grail and 42 is a Douglas Adams reference.

Answer (score 0):

Python already has checks for invalid keyword arguments. Just use the built-in mechanisms:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *, a=1, b=2, c=3):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class MyChildClass(MyClass):
    def __init__(self, *, d=4, e=5, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
```

Any invalid keyword arguments will get rejected by `MyClass.__init__`. (Positional arguments will be rejected because these parameters are defined as keyword-only.)

Comment: @Corralien: [That's not what I get when I run it.](https://ideone.com/aORYHf)

Comment: I tried to replace `*` by `/`. I don't really understand the logic of this two symbols, especially `/`.

Comment: @Corralien: Anything before `/` is positional-only. Anything after `*` is keyword-only.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I know it's off topic but if I understand well `str.join(self, iterable, /)` means you can pass as many positional arguments as you want but no keywords. So `iterable` contains a list of all positional arguments?

Comment: @Corralien: No. You can pass it exactly one positional argument, an iterable of strings to join.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, you're solving a different problem than what I'm needing help with.  I want to do all this via `**kwargs* so I don't have a whole ton of explicit keyword arguments in the `__init__` method.  The actual code where this is applicable has a ton of inheritance with a ton of parameters that get set at various levels.

Comment: @Chad: But moving all that to `_kwargs_def` isn't any better. Your answer has way more boilerplate than mine does.

Comment: @Chad: Plus, your answer is [much slower](https://ideone.com/TQ2DY2), and gets even worse as more levels of inheritance are added, because the use of both `MyClass()._kwargs_def` and `super().__init__(...)` means it calls the superclass constructor twice, and that means in a deeper inheritance hierarchy, it calls super-superclass constructors 4 times, and super-super-superclass constructors 8 times, and so on.

Comment: @Chad: Actually, your answer doesn't work. [It fails if you try to provide `a`, `b`, or `c` when constructing a `MyChildClass` instance.](https://ideone.com/derXJ3) (I've had to change the `assert`s to `if` checks because ideone disables assertions by default, but the class definitions are otherwise unmodified.)